# scalable background image wih a matching horizontal nav

Tags: html, css, background, center, nav

I'm trying to keep the position of the horizontal nav bar in "sync", so to speak, with the scalable background image. Right now it seems the nav is staticly positioned while the image moves freely when the browser is resized. I dunno if this is even really possible to be honest. Here's the sites homepage:

www.nickducot.com/parker_new/

Here's the code that I've got so far:

HTML:
http://pastebin.com/TjJprLAv

CSS
http://pastebin.com/jzYRQPt2

Maybe media queries/responsive design would help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough outline of one way you could do it. It involves putting the image in the markup, not as a background.

HTML

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="imagefile.jpg">
    <div id="menu">
        ... menu
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image-wrapper {
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 700px;
    /* Note the above numbers are untested and plucked out of thin air for example purposes */
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
.image-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Edit: note the menu won't actually change size, but it *will* be anchored to a certain point of the image. You will also need to play around with all the pixel values I used to achieve your desired effect.